# python-cant install scipy from wheel

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, python-wheel

I am trying to install scipy using pip from this wheel file:
scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
I have already install numpy+mkl of the same python version and win32 version. Numpy was installed successfully, But when I tried installing scipy, it is showing these error messages :

```
C:\Users\Saurav Agarwal\Downloads>pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\saurav agarwal\downloads\scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 484, in unzip_file
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "c:\python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Please help me out regarding this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could copy the whole error message in as text into the post (indent it by highlighting and pressing Ctrl+K) to get proper formatting. The image seems to have the bottom part of the error message cropped off.

Comment: I am not able to copy the whole error message as it is in command prompt  window and I am not able to copy from there.

Comment: You can still copy from the command prompt ([this guide may be helpful](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx?mfr=true)).

Comment: edit done. Please help me now.